# Input Group prepend - Bootstrap - can a reset button be included on the side of the input?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, prepend

I have an input with a prepend from Bootstrap, looks nice and modifiable. I know I can put another button on the other side, but can that button be a reset? I have tried multiple things. Here is what I know and I will attach pictures below.

```
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">Your calculation</span>
            </div>
            <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 2)" id="userInputMapOne" class="form-control" min="0" max="1000" step="0.01" aria-label="input value for your zone" value="e.g 12.34">
```

This is the current code I am using, it is **NOT** wrapped in a form. When I wrap it in a form things stop working for a strange reason. I am already having troubles with this, the min/max and step don't work (I have controlled min/max and step with JavaScript). So, is there a way to prepend (or append at the same time as a prepend) a second button onto that input and without being in a form and use that to clear the input field back to the default of ""?

It seemed like an easy job but this constantly interfered with the data being input. And for a weird reason, I can't seem to put a form just wrapping this input without upsetting the divs.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: While this would certainly work I think it would be in your bests
> interests to review why a `<form>` is interfering with the
> functionality of your code.

You cannot add a true `<button type="reset">...</button>` because you are not using a `<form>` and so the reset button doesn't know what to actually 'do'.  You can quickly do something similar with just a few modifications of your existing code:

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Your calculation</span>
  </div>

  <input type="number" id="calculation" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 2)" id="userInputMapOne" class="form-control" min="0" max="1000" step="0.01" aria-label="input value for your zone" value="e.g 12.34">

  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button role="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="document.getElementById('calculation').value = ''">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

First you need to add an ID to your input field so that you can easily target the field with a bit of JavaScript.  Then you just need to add an `.input-group-append` to extend the `input-group` to include the new button we'll be adding.

The button operates just like any button would, with the exception that there is an `onclick` event:

`document.getElementById('calculation').value = ''`

This finds the field with an ID value of `calculation` and on a click event resets the value of that field to empty.  It's not a reset in the true sense of how `<button type="reset">...</button>` would operate, but functionally it achieves the same result.

Comment: I will get some screenshots of what happens when I add form (I forgot to do that in the OP). But you're right, I need to see why form is messing with the code.

Comment: I fixed the form... I don't know why it didn't work the other day properly. Maybe I didn't close the tag... I really don't know. But now it is working and I have a reset button there now too.

Comment: In your original code sample you are missing a closing `</div>` for the `input-group` wrapper. Maybe that was the issue.

Comment: The div is there, I accidentally cut it off when copying the code. But good spotting :)